# Sending an updated value to a service on field change which is already executed once for a previous value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call an 3rd party api by sending some input parameters through an angular js service.: **recordService.js**

```
function getRecordId(price, itemId){
    angularLoad.loadScript('https://3rdpartyapi')
    .then(function() {
        Button.render({ 
            method1: function(data, actions) {
                var parameters = {
                        price: price,
                        itemId : itemId
                }
                return internalHttpRequestMethod
                    ({
                        endpoint: 'save.php',
                        parameters: parameters
                    })
                .then(function(response) {
                    if(response.recordId){
                        return response.recordtId;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                })
            }

}
```

This service gets data from a component which passes the price and itemId to the service's function:

```
recordService.getRecordId(price.value, itemId)
```

But I've called the service in `onInit` method because, I want the script to be executed and render the button initially. So, it is calling the script passing `price="0"` or `price=null`.

When I update the price value, later the button was rendered, it is still taking the value as `0` or `null`.

I've tried calling the service each time I change the price field value also, though it causes performance issues, but still not working (price not getting updated in service).

Is there any better approach to this, i.e. to update the value of `price` on field change and save it to internal `save.php`?

Edit: I've added this function in the service on field change, still no use:

```
function updateProice(price){
    price = price;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are some missing closing braces and parens. Is that because you snipped the code?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `internalHttpRequestMethod` function. An $http response object does not normally have a `recordId` property and an $http config object does not normally have an `endpoint` property.